# What is the most efficient design for a human powered aircraft limited to 30mph at 100ft?

Tags: aircraft-design

What is the most efficient design for an aircraft limited to a maximum velocity of 30mph at a maximum altitude of 100ft?
The objective is to minimize drag and weight.
The payload would be 1 human, and my budget is approximately 100,000 dollars (more can be done) for materials I was thinking airloys (because they are light and strong). The end goal is to go more than 74 miles on flat train using human power.

My guesses are aircrafts shaped like a sail plane or a Ground Effect Vehicles (GEVs).

Comment: Payload and function would also be important design factors.

Comment: I added important details is it enough to re open the question?

Comment: @mins For a human-powered aircraft, wouldn't the range be mostly a function of how long it takes the pilot to get tired/hungry?

Comment: This question still seems very broad. What kind of 'efficiency' are you talking about? Just the least power input on the part of the human to sustain flight? If it's that, wouldn't the answer basically just be "Use a glider and forget the human-powered part?"

Comment: @Frvgdf Keep explaining - this question still isn't really answerable. Your details add some context but they also don't help the question if you're truly asking about efficiency rather than constructing an aircraft.

Comment: @mins Ah, so I see. I guess I should have looked at the edit history first.

Comment: @mins yeah sorry I was meaning human powered but there are plenty of human powered aircraft that look like sail planes but there are not very many that look like GEVs so I did not know if I would be able to get an awnser if I said human powered

Comment: @reirab when I ask about efficiency I am asking about the least drag and weight how would you say I phrase that?

Comment: @digitgopher so I am asking about the most effecent normal aircraft so that I can possibly apply some of the principles of that aircraft (except for getting into thin air to reduce drag that can not be done) and apply them to a human powered aircraft.

Comment: It looks like you're asking something that normally takes a team of engineers to answer, and judging by the variety of aircraft out there, ten engineers will give you eleven different answers.

Comment: It would probably be shaped something like Daedalus:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_Daedalus